# kivy doesn't show the window

Tags: python, kivy

after I write a code to show a window with text "name" and a dialog box, I got no error. However for me window doesn't show. and I got no error. does anyone any Idea about that?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
 def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.cols = 2
    self.add_widget(Label(text="name"))
    self.name = TextInput(multilines=False)
    self.add_widget(self.name)


class MyApp(App):
 def build(self):
    return MyGrid()

if __name__ == "__name__":
  MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Change `if __name__ == "__name__":` to `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Mai I ask you to help me with another question that I asked